# Restrict which requests a ServletDispatcher processes

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

Can you control which requests specific `DispatcherServlet` instances are allowed to issue? I have defined two dispatchers, one to service requests for `/public/public*` and another for `private/private*`.

Here are my dispatchers

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
         SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
   }
   @Bean
   public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServletPublic() {
      return new DispatcherServlet();
   }
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletPublicRegistration() {
      ServletRegistrationBean registration =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServletPublic(), "/public/public*");
      registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
      return registration;
   }
   @Bean
   public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServletPrivate() {
      return new DispatcherServlet();
   }
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletPrivateRegistration() {
      ServletRegistrationBean registration =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServletPublic(), "/private/private*");
      registration.setName("private");
      return registration;
   }
}
```

The the request mappings.

```
@RestController
public class RmbOneController {
   @RequestMapping("/public-data")
   public String publicData() {
       return "Here is your data: 42.";
   }
   @RequestMapping("/private-data")
   public String privateData() {
      return "Here is your PRIVATE data: 43.";
   }
}
```

This doesn't work. I am getting the Whitelabel Error Page with these two URLs. Not that the context root for this WAR is `/`.

```
http://localhost:8080/private/private-data
http://localhost:8080/public/public-data
```

And a few items I am confused about

- I was trying it this way because it's close to what we would do with servlet mappings - define which servlet class would respond to givens URLs.

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>PublicServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ...
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>PublicServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>foo.bar.PublicServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  ```
- I was thinking that this might be the way to implement public and private areas - that later I would put login filters on the private dispatcher. I see on the page [Spring Boot features - Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html) that my assumption about this being the way to start authentication is probably wrong. (I haven't had time yet to go further into it).
- Soooo... is it possible to restrict which requests a dispatcher can process.
- And why might it be done this way?

Comment: And why would it be different in this case... Just map using what you would do in `web.xml`. The fact that you use java doesn't change the mapping rules...

Comment: however you would have to have multiple contexts also, now your /public also allows access to private data. Why not simply use a single servlet and use proper security ...

Comment: @M.Deinum "Just map using what you would do in web.xml" honestly I thought I was doing that. The second parameter to `ServletRegistrationBean` is `urlMappings` so I am thinking that *is* the equivalent of a `servlet-mapping`. Which is part of why I am asking this question, to find out what is the correct equivalent, if this isn't it.

Comment: @M.Deinum "Why not simply use a single servlet and use proper security". I guess I didn't explain myself too well: I have concluded that this isn't the way to implement public/private areas - fine, I will work out how to do that properly soon enough. But right now I am trying to figure out why these two separate dispatchers are not acting equivalently to two servlet mappings, and if there are any legitimate cases in which you would want to use different dispatchers with mutually exclusive requests that they can respond to.

Comment: They don't because a) you are sharing a single context b) the mapping is different and the controllers are mapped inside the servlet path.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you are trying to explain. :/
What I do understand is that both servlets (`DispatcherServlet` instances) share the context root because they are in the same web-app/war - context root in this case is set to `/`.

Comment: the context root has nothing to do with an `ApplicationContext` (which is what I meant) they share all the beans because they are using the same `ApplicationContext`. The mapping doesn't work because with the mapping you specified the controllers will never be reached. The URL on the controllers is the part AFTER the application context path and servlet path. However here you are trying to match a part of your servlet-path onto the controller mapping.

Comment: Ok, that part clicked. 1) The `@Controller` is a bean in the `ApplicationContext` which both `ServletDispatcher`s share, so both dispatchers will be able respond to all requests defined in the controller. 2) the request URI is created (in part) by adding the servlet path + path info (`@RequestMapping`). The servlet path is not something that gets matched against target `@RequestMapping` paths. It is a different paradigm to the way servlet-mapping was used because instead of saying "match this URL to this servlet" we say "match this URL to this servlet which invokes this request".